# Tamil fonts not rendering properly in chrome and microsoft edge

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

Recently installed ubuntu 23.10, Chrome and microsoft edge browsers not rendering tamil font properly, some text showing box or crossed box, But in Firefox working fine. how to fix this issue.

check this image some text displayed as box

[image]

youtube title showing as crossed box when i hover the cursor to title it rendering font correctly.

[image]

Comment: Try `sudo apt install fonts-taml`, then close and reopen the browser. Does that help?

Comment: No,  

**fonts-taml is already the newest version (2:1.4)**

Comment: Ok, let's try `sudo apt install fonts-noto-extra fonts-noto`. Then reopen the browser.

Comment: Installed but problem not solved.

Comment: How did you install the browsers, snap or deb?

Comment: deb, downloaded from official websites

Comment: Have you tried to change the font settings in Chrome?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson No, using default font settings in chrome and edge

Comment: I meant that it may be worth a try to do so.

Comment: Thankyou, after changing default standard font to tamil unicode font, now text rendering properly

Answer (score 0):

Like @Archisman Panigrahi mentioned in the comments, following procedure worked for me..

If you are using Debian 12 and above open terminal and run this command as 'root' user privileges.

```
sudo apt install fonts-taml
```

Then close and reopen browser window.